How to naturally define a topology on an algebraic structure using its own substructures
A month ago, I was thinking about how to construct a topological space similar to the Zariski topology on the spectrum of a ring. After more than a month of effort, I did manage to construct some topologies, but they are quite different from the Zariski topology. Therefore, I would like to ask if anyone has suggestions on how to use the substructures of an algebraic structure to construct topologies? The method I used mainly involves partial orders, which is rather trivial. (My English is not very good, so I used GPT to help translate my question. I hope for your understanding.)
Specific description: Given an algebraic structure  H , which has some substructures, how can we use these substructures to define a topological space on  H ? Structurally, the prime spectrum of a ring is simply a topology on a ring (strictly speaking, a topology on prime ideals) defined by the inclusion relation among prime ideals and general ideals. Therefore, my question is whether there are other examples of such constructions? Can this approach be generalized to a more general case?

Maybe this is relevant: B. Plotkin "Seven lectures on universal algebraic geometry" https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0204245

The question is not focussed enough. It is not clear what your question really is.

Sorry, my description was not specific enough. I have re-explained my idea in more detail.@Martin Brandenburg

I briefly went through the introduction, and it does seem helpful. I will read this report in my future research. Thank you for sharing!@Vladimir Lysikov

This is something I thought about for a long time but I never found any examples other than ring-like ones. I think this is because to have any interesting geometry we need unions and intersections, and we also expect distributivity, so we are already halfway to the ring axioms…

I have actually created some specific examples and abstracted such a structure, but I feel that the geometric meaning behind it is too simple. If you’re willing, we can discuss it in more detail?@Zhen Lin

There are a few ways of thinking about the Zariski topology, each of which leads to potentially different generalisations.
The first (oldest, most classical) point of view comes from the idea that algebraic geometry is about the solution locus of equations.
This is easy to generalise.
Given an algebraic structure $A$:

A solution locus is a subset $Z \subseteq A^n$ such that there is a (possibly infinite) set $E$ of equations of terms in the language of $A$ with $n$ variables with the property that an $n$-tuple is in $Z$ if and only if it satisfies all the equations in $E$.

A closed subset of $A^n$ is a union of finitely many solution loci.


Notice that when $A$ is an integral domain, some things simplify:

We can always rearrange an equation so that (say) the RHS is the constant $0$, so we can replace sets of equations with sets of polynomials and talk about the zero locus instead of the solution locus.

We can pairwise multiply two sets of polynomials to get a set of polynomials whose zero locus is the union of the zero loci of the original sets of polynomials, so we do not need to distinguish between the concepts of zero locus and closed subset.


The first simplification is not so hard to generalise: for instance, if $A$ has some notion of "subtraction" and "zero".
The second simplification is harder – I don't know if it can even be made to work for (commutative) rings with zero divisors!
However, it is certain that the notions of solution/zero locus and closed subset must be different in general: for example, if $A$ is a 1-dimensional vector space, then solution loci in $A^n$ are vector subspaces as usual, but as everyone knows, the union of two vector subspaces is not always a vector subspace.

A more sophisticated point of view is inspired by functional analysis.
The inputs are an algebraic structure $A$, a set $X$, and for each $x \in X$ a congruence $=_x$ on $A$.
The idea is that $A$ is an algebra of "functions" on a space, $X$ is the set of "points" of that space, and the congruence $=_x$ tell us which "functions" have equal "values" at $x$.
This induces a topology on $X$ in basically the same way: first we define solution loci, then we define closed subsets to be finitary unions of solution loci.
Something interesting happens if all the congruences $=_x$ are prime, i.e. $=_x$ is not all of $A \times A$ and given any congruences $\equiv$ and $\equiv'$ on $A$, if $=_x$ contains the intersection of $\equiv$ and $\equiv'$, then $=_x$ contains either $\equiv$ or $\equiv'$ (or both).
If every $=_x$ is prime, then the union of two solution loci is another solution locus – so we no longer need to distinguish between solution loci and general closed subsets.
(The "prime" terminology is not a coincidence: this is a generalisation of the trick we used for integral domains to get unions!
However, it is subtly and strictly more general than the standard notion of prime ideal: see here.)
If $A$ is genuinely an algebra of functions (meaning functions taking values in some algebraic structure of the same signature, with algebraic operations on the functions being defined pointwise), there is an obvious choice for $X$ and $=_x$, but what if $A$ is just some abstract algebraic structure?
Well, since $=_x$ has to be a congruence on $A$, we could take $X$ to be the set of all congruences on $A$ or any subset thereof, such as the set of prime congruences on $A$ mentioned just now, or an even smaller subset if necessary to obtain better properties (e.g. functoriality).
Applying this to the case where $A$ is a commutative ring, we recover the prime spectrum of Chevalley, Grothendieck, et al.
However, it is dangerous to focus on just prime congruences: for example, if $A$ is a vector space of dimension $\ge 2$, there are no prime congruences on $A$ at all.
It is also unclear whether the pullback of a prime congruence along an arbitrary homomorphism is automatically prime.

So much for equations and closed subsets.
There is one more crucial ingredient in the success story of modern algebraic geometry: the structure sheaf.
The structure sheaf is the device that allows us to endow open subsets with an algebra of functions and hence consider them as algebra-ed spaces in their own right; without the structure sheaf, we would only be able to do so for solution loci (not even general closed subsets!), and we would not have any local theory of algebra.
Unfortunately, this is the one thing that seems to defy generalisation.
At the heart of the construction of the structure sheaf of the spectrum of a commutative ring is the fact that "$x = 0$" and "$x$ is invertible" are essentially mutually exclusive propositions about elements of a commutative ring.
We can force an element to be $0$ by passing to the quotient, and we can force an element to be invertible by passing to the localisation.
Not coincidentally, the former is how we get the algebra of functions on a basic closed subset (modulo nilpotents) and the latter is how we get the algebra of functions on a basic open subset.
Although there is a formal duality between open and closed subsets (at least if we believe the law of excluded middle), the duality between "$x = 0$" and "$x$ is invertible" seems far from formal to me.
At least, there does not seem to be any general abstract nonsense that explains where the "$x$ is invertible" side comes from.
